# What is the purpose of using super.init creating custom view with xib?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to understand why we use super.init all the time.

For example,

```
class HeaderStyle1: UIView {


var subview: UIView! //NİB


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    commonInit()
}

func commonInit(){
    subview = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderStyle1", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
    subview.frame = bounds
    subview.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    addSubview(subview)

}
```

First: When I instantiate

```
header = HeaderStyle1(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 80))
```

super.init(frame: frame) instantiates UIView. Why we need this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var header: HeaderStyle1!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createView()     }


    func createView() {

        //Create Header
        header = HeaderStyle1(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.fr
        self.view.addSubview(header)
```

}

Second: I add header to UIViewController view as subview. Here header is an instance of HeaderStyle1. So I actually add a class to UIViewController view. How does UIViewController view show instance as view? Is it because of super.init or something?
Thank you

```
self.view.addSubview(header)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** , as every class is a subclass of another You call `super.init` is done to insure that if you call some *Instance Variable / Method* of the super class, you'll be able to do so as the super class is successfully initiated

[image]

suppose that i sublassed NSArray and in some point in app i want to call

```
  NSArray*er = [myArr mutableCopy];
```

the copy process will fail if `[super init];` failed when i subclassed `NSArray`
as mutableCopy is a method in `NSObject` that i ignored it's super init

**Second** , you actually adding an instance of a `UIView` (HeaderStyle1) to the current view controller's view (which also an instance of UIView) not class to class , this is a hierarchy made by **Apple** so developers can add different views to their apps to satisfy certain layout needs and modularize their Design so on for all UIKit components (UILabel,UITextfeild.....) that are pre-designed in IOS frameworks to display common components that make sense in small Mobile devices

Comment: second, it is not , what is it?